# LINQ Query with ODATA The method 'Select' is not supported

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I use the code from this link 
[How to return both parent and child using LINQ against 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994383/how-to-return-both-parent-and-child-using-linq-against-1-table)
My goal is to relate project and sub project in dashboard.

I use LInQPad to execute this query and I use the data from odata MS Project Online:

https://[mysite].sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/

```
from parents in Projects // parents is only used to decide which children to get
from all in Projects // this is where we will actually grab our data from
where
    parents.ParentProjectId == null && // and that are parents
    (
        (all.ParentProjectId == null && all.ProjectId == parents.ProjectId) ||  // If entry is a parent, match with itself to limit returns to 1
        all.ParentProjectId == parents.ProjectId // otherwise, parentid should match one of the valid parents.
    )
select all
```

But this returns error

```
The method 'Select' is not supported.
```

Any suggestion so I can fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: OData is rather limited in terms of it's implementation of the full LINQ syntax. For a join like this I would prefer to pull down the data required and then perform the join locally. i.e. I would pull down "all" as well as "parents" and then perform a regular .NET based LINQ expression between the two (now local) data sources.